# How to render only new items in a react list and not re render the whole list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, timeout

**My problem** is when I have more than one object in the state every item of the list re-renders and they each have a deletion timeout (I want them to be deleted after an amount of time) which is reset at each re-render.

**I tried** to use React.memo() and React.useCallback() to prevent the item in the list to re-render when adding new items but since I recreate the array each time I add or remove a todo the values passed to list items are renewed and the items re-render.

I tried like in the code example to pass as props only values of the items and not an entire object but that not changed anything

This is a gif to illustrate my problem, but you have a code Sandbox too (just below) to see by yourself

[image: Gif example of my problem]

- In the first part of the video everything is going well
- but when I click 2 times I expect the items to get deleted 3s after getting rendered, but only the last item gets deleted then the list disappears then the first is deleted

**Here is a code Sandbox** with the code below inside
[image: Edit Wawa]

index.js

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import Todos from "./Todos";

const App = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  const addTodo = () => {
    setTodos((todos) => [
      ...todos,
      {
        id: new Date().getTime(),
        message: new Date().getSeconds()
      }
    ]);
  };

  const deleteTodo = (todoID) => {
    const newTodos = todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== todoID);

    setTodos((t) => [...newTodos]);
  };

  return <Todos todos={todos} addTodo={addTodo} deleteTodo={deleteTodo} />;
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

Todos.js

```js
import Todo from "./todo";

const Todos = ({ todos, addTodo, deleteTodo }) => {
  console.log("\nTodoList render");
  return (
    <>
      <h2>My Todos</h2>
      {todos.map((todo, index) => {
        return (
          <Todo
            key={index}
            todomessage={todo.message}
            id={todo.id}
            deleteTodo={deleteTodo}
          />
        );
      })}
      <button onClick={addTodo}>Add Todo</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Todos;
```

todo.js

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";

const Todo = ({ todomessage, id, deleteTodo }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("todo " + todomessage + " rendered");

    setTimeout(() => {
      deleteTodo(id);
      console.log("todo " + todomessage + " rendered 3s ago");
    }, 3000);
  });

  return <p>{todomessage}</p>;
};

export default Todo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the declaration of `newTodos` inside the `setTodos` callback and use the `todos` parameter instead of the `todos` variable from the `useState` call (since it will end up being stale due to the `setTimeout`):

```js
const deleteTodo = (todoID) => {
  setTodos((todos) => {
    const newTodos = todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== todoID);
    return newTodos
  });
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for the quick answer and explanation !! I didn't even know that I could access the state by this way so it will help me in the future